# Как можно стилизовать вводимый текст и placeholder в input?

Tags: css3

[image: требуемый дизайн]

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли сделать так чтобы и placeholder располагался в input с таким отступом, и текст при вводе тоже? У меня получилось так что и placeholder и вводимый текст прижат к левому краю.

Answer (score 3):

Для отступов в input

```
input{
  padding:0 20px;
}
```

Стилизовать отдельно placeholdr можно с помощью псевдоклассов

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#222; font-size:16px; font-family: 'RalewayRegular',"Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;}
input::-moz-placeholder          {color:#222; opacity:2; font-size:16px; font-family: 'RalewayRegular',"Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;}/* Firefox 19+ */
input:-moz-placeholder           {color:#222; opacity:2; font-size:16px; font-family: 'RalewayRegular',"Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;}/* Firefox 18- */
input:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#222; font-size:16px; font-family: 'RalewayRegular',"Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:transparent;}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color:transparent;}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color:transparent;}
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:transparent;}
```